# iphone getting user location at time intervals

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gps, core-location, cllocationmanager

I browsed through some of the questions in stackoverflow but I couldn't get a clear picture. I am working on an iPhone application that involves getting the user's location through GPS and processing based on the value that I got. I just wanted to make sure that how should I implement this? Using this method :

```
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation]
```

gives me the accurate location but it keeps on updating often that I do not want. I would like to get the user's location on a periodic basis.i.e., like every 2 minutes. How do I implement that?

The method I thought (10 second interval):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { 
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init]; 
    locationManager.delegate = self; 
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest; 
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    NSTimer *currentTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(theActionMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

and in the action method for the timer :

```
- (void)theActionMethod {
     [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

and the method didUpdatetoLocation:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
     self.startingPoint = newLocation;
     NSString *latitudeString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g\u00B0", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
     NSLog([@"Latitude : " stringByAppendingString:latitudeString]);
     [latitudeString release];
     [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Now I am getting a value that remains the same throughout. Every 10s the location is updated but all values remain the same (I tried printing longitude, horizontal accuracy,altitude,vertical accuracy etc.). So please help me how to get the exact(atleast somewhat accurate because I know that GPS is not accurate)user's location for every 2 minutes.

And I would also like to know how to implement the monitoringRegions and significantlocationchange thing. Does anyone successfully implemented it? I couldn't do it. I did not notice any change (I printed something in didEnterRegion which was never printed even when I went back and forth in and out of the region ). Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: This is two questions; you should ask 2 separate questions.  And your monitoringRegions is too general - what exactly didn't work?  
Now, back to your main question: are you testing this in a car/train/bus/plane/boat so that the actual location will change every 10 seconds?  If you're just sitting at your desk, the GPS location will be the same every time (after an initial zeroing in).

Comment: I should have asked it as 2 questions. Anyways, I am not sure how monitoringRegions work. Like how frequently does it update? While moving, Consider we cross the region in 10s(enter and exit within 10s), Will it notify me of this? I was testing by walking in and out of my approximate monitoringRegion.

Comment: What level of accuracy are you expecting?  I don't know the exact limit, but 100 meters is probably close.  In other words, GPS will not be able to determine (accurately) that you've only moved 75 meters.

Answer (score 2):

Just do that same thing you're already doing. Just ignore the delegate method and change `theActionMethod:` to use the `locationManager.location` property however you want.

Comment: Hi, just wanted to know more about the working.. so do you intend to say that the delegate method can be removed and just use the `locationManager.location` to get the updated location values in `theActionMethod`? Could you point me to any resources that would help me learn doing it that way or it would be great if you can make an edit on how to do that.. Thanks.